# what API Gateway methods support Authorization?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

When I create a resource/method in AWS API Gateway API I can create one of the following methods: `DELETE`, `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, `PATCH` or `POST`.

If I choose `GET` then API Gateway doesn't pass authentication details; but for `POST` it does.

For `GET` should I be adding the cognito credentials to the URL of my `GET`? or just never use `GET` and use `POST` for all authenticated calls?

**My set-up in API Gateway/Lambda:**

I created a Resource and two methods: `GET` and `POST`
Under Authorization Settings I set Authorization to `AWS_AIM`
For this example there is no `Request Model`

Under Method Execution I set Integration type to Lambda Function and I check `Invoke with caller credentials` (I also set Lambda Region and Lambda Function)
I leave `Credentials cache` unchecked.

For Body Mapping Templates, I set `Content-Type` to `application/json' and the Mapping Template to

```
{ "identity" : "$input.params('identity')"}
```

In my Python Lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print context.identity
    print context.identity.cognito_identity_id

    return True
```

**Running the Python function:**

For the `GET` context.identity is None
For the `POST` context.identity has a value and `context.identity.cognito_identity_id` has the correct value.

Comment: All methods support authentication. Are you sure you enabled authentication for the method before testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments: all HTTP methods support authentication. If the method is configured to require authentication, authentication results *should* be included in the context for you to access via mapping templates to pass down stream as contextual information.

If this is not working for you, please update your question to reflect:

1. How your API methods are configured.
2. What your mapping template is.
3. What results you see in testing.

**UPDATE**

The code in your lambda function is checking the context of the **Lambda** function, not the value from API Gateway. To access the value passed in from API Gateway, you would need to use `event.identity` not `context.identity`.

This would only half solve your problem as you are not using the correct value to access the identity in API gateway. That would be `$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId` (assuming you are using Amazon Cognito auth). Please see the [mapping template reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) for a full guide of supported variables.

Finally, you may want to consider using the template referenced [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265445/parse-aws-api-gateway-header-in-lambda).

Comment: thanks Bob. I can now see that I can access the user's id from my Lambda function using context.identity.cognito_identity_id - and not specify anything in my APIG mapping templates. Much cleaner. I knew you must be offering a clean solution :) just took a while to work it out